# RealityKit Model Entity will be darker when I use ARWorldTrackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

RealityKit Model Entity will be darker when I use ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.
When I place a Model Entity without ARWorldTrackingConfiguration, it is displayed brightly.
Why? And does someone know how can I fix it?

May the force be with you and me.

Answer (score 0):

This have been solved in Apple Developer Forum (thank you gchiste.)

```
let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
```